# Program skips one value in array when I am using Java

Tags: java

How can I add the last value since array starts from zero?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
        int numplay = x.nextInt();
        int players[]= new int[numplay];
        for(int y=0;y<numplay ;y++)
        {
            if(y > 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Goals score by player #"+ y +": ");
                players[y]=x.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of players: 4
Goals score by player #1: 1
Goals score by player #2: 2
Goals score by player #3: 3
```

Desired output:

```
Enter the number of players: 4
Goals score by player #1: 1
Goals score by player #2: 2
Goals score by player #3: 3
Goals score by player #4: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not prompting for the last player because you skip the first iteration of the loop due to the `if (y > 0)` condition. Consider this code:

```
Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
int numplay = x.nextInt();
int players[]= new int[numplay];
int y; 
for(int i=0; i < numplay; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Goals score by player #"+ (i+1) +": ");
    y = x.nextInt();
    players[i]=y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the value of `y` plus one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
    int numplay = x.nextInt();
    int players[] = new int[numplay];
    for (int y = 0; y < numplay; y++) {
        System.out.print("Goals score by player #" + (y + 1) + ": ");
        players[y] = x.nextInt();
    }
}
```

By putting `y + 1` in brackets, inside call to `print`, Java understands that it means add operation and not string concatenation.

Running above code gives me this output:

```
Enter the number of players: 4
Goals score by player #1: 1
Goals score by player #2: 2
Goals score by player #3: 3
Goals score by player #4: 4
```